# retrofit2.0 : create and execute request manually

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have following data with me that comes dynamically:

```
Url, 
Http Method, 
List of Headers (key-value pair), 
List of Parameters(key-value pair), 
Body Text (Plain) or Form Data (Key-value pair; value could be text or file).
```

Is there any way I can create whole new Retrofit request using this data ?

Something like:

```
request.setUrl(url);
request.setMethod(method);
for(Headers){ request.addHeader("key", "value"); }
for(Parameters){ request.addParameter("key", "value"); }
request.setBody(textBody);
for(FormData){ request.addParameter("key", "value"); }
```

Could anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use OkHttp Interceptor to dynamically set those.  There is an example of dynamically setting host under [samples](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/samples/src/main/java/com/example/retrofit/DynamicBaseUrl.java).